# Filter in URL redirection is not working

Tags: search, redirection

There is a filter at "admin/config/search/redirect" that allows to search specific redirect entry. When I enter some value in the text-box and click on "Filter", I do not get filtered list. Instead, the filter box gets disappeared. I also tried to uninstall and re-install the latest version but the issue still persists.

This issue never occurred before and recently I am seeing this issue.